# Find all differentiable equations using Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. I want to use the Cauchy Riemann equations to find all differentiable functions of the form
$$Re( h(z))=2x^2+2x+1-2y^2$$


So I used the C-R equations with $u(x,y)=2x^2+2x+1-2y^2$:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= 4x+2=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \quad \quad \implies v=4xy+2y+h(y)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -4y=- \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \quad \quad \implies v=4xy+g(x)$$

But I don't really know what this means for the value of $v$. Obviously both terms match up with the $4xy$, but then what about the extra terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thus far you have
$$v=4xy+2y+h(y)=4xy+g(x).$$
This means 
$$2y+h(y)=g(x).$$
Left side is a function of $y$ (only) and right side is that of $x$ (only) but the two have to be equal. This can only happen if both of them are constant functions. So
\begin{align*}
g(x) & = c\\
h(y) & = -2y+c
\end{align*}
Thus $v=4xy+c$.

Comment: What would have happened if I had unequal terms on each side of the equation, for instance $v=\frac{1}{2}y^2 +h(y)=- \frac{1}{2}x^2 +g(x)$ from the function $u=xy?$ Would this mean the function is not differentiable?